# Disable windows authentication on single location

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a web application and I want to provide anonymous access to a couple of the web services in it so that we can access the web services from computers without a windows login on our network.

I've tried the stuff here [Disable authentication on subfolder(s) of an ASP.NET app using windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713192/disable-authentication-on-subfolders-of-an-asp-net-app-using-windows-authentica).  I've done this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

...

```
  <location path="Tests/QService.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

These both "work" in that they allow access to the web service for anonymous users.  However, it seems that IIS still sends an authorization challange because when I access the service from a browser I get a box to enter my username and password.  If I hit cancel I get access to the page anonymously.  However, some of our clients don't handle this well and just fail because of the 401 return code.

Is there a way to completely disable the windows authentication on that single location such that IIS will not try and establish a windows authentication?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the settings on your Virtual Directory in IIS.  Which version of IIS are you using?  What are the enabled authentication settings on the Virtual Dir?

Comment: IIS 7.5.  I have Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication enabled.

Comment: @tster @richm - answers are for the purpose of ONLY answering a question. They are not there for use by other users to elicit further information for their own purposes or to solve a similar problem by asking another question. Stack Overflow is *not* a forum. Replying to a "question-as-an-answer" with an edit to said answer is also not permitted. Just so you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev, What on earth are you talking about?   Did you remove some comments or something?  I honestly have no idea what you mean by `Replying to a "question-as-an-answer" with an edit to said answer`.  This was my question, and I would assume all the comments and edits I have made were to make the question more clear or provide further details that I left out.

Comment: @tster - there was an answer by Rich M (now deleted) which said *"Sorry..this is not an "answer". I couldnt see how to post a "comment" Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue.* - you edited this answer and posted a reply starting with *Edit from OP: Try this in your global.asax*. This is not permitted.

Comment: @Kev, I remember that now.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

You need to disable Windows Authentication on the Virtual Directory for that single location.  Then you shouldn't be challenged.

Comment: This works, but I don't want to have to modify the config of every IIS instance that I publish to.  I'd rather have a web.config or code solution.