# How to disable window authentication for single HealthCheck.aspx page in my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I want to disable window authentication for single HealthCheck.aspx page in my application,my application is using window authentication for user verification.

I already followed this approach in the link

1. [Disable windows authentication on single location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222556/disable-windows-authentication-on-single-location)

but in this approach is not working.

2. select the file in content view, click switch to feature view on right Actions pane, then you disable Windows Authentication for this
   specific file.

after following above two approach I did not get any solution can any one help me...

Thank you in advance
Improve

Comment: Did you allow both Windows authenticated and anonymous users in IIS as well? In `IIS Manager` you need to click the `Authentication` icon and enable `Anonymous Authentication`. After doing this, the web.config settings should work.

Comment: yes what you are saying is correct, but my requirement is to disable window authentication only for single HealthCheck.aspx page which exist in my application and left of all resource of application should be able to access through the valid authorized users only :)

Comment: The way it works is you enable anonymous authentication in IIS and then use the web.config to set which parts of the site require what type of authentication. If you do not enable anonymous authentication is IIS, no request can be anonymous, and nothing you do anywhere else will help.

Comment: If your site has **any** anonymous pages, you must allow anonymous access in IIS as well.