# Disable forms authentication for debugging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working with an application that consists of many independent modules and where user authentication is handled by its own module as well.

Each application uses an [Authorize] attribute on top of each controller and web.config that points to security module:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="/SecurityModule/Account/LogOn" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
```

When I hit F5 to start up the application it fails: "The resource cannot be found." The security module is not installed and log in page cannot be found.

At this point all I want to do is to be able to hit F5 and run this specific web app and remove the security dependency and add it back at build time.

And before I get hit with "This is a duplicate of this Question": There are many question out there on the subject and i read many of the Q&A, but could not find anything that I could use.
For example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839406/forms-authentication-disable-redirect-to-the-login-page).

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713192/disable-authentication-on-subfolders-of-an-asp-net-app-using-windows-authentic ?

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution to disable authentication just for debugging, but it seems that there is no easy way around this. I'm currently looking into custom AuthorizeAttribute implementation.