# Enable anonymous authentication to a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7.5

I have an application on the server (www.foo.com) that requires login. It is hosted in IIS 7.5. I've created a new sub-directory underneath it and hosted a web service (www.foo.com/ws). I've also copied the code-behind dll to the bin folder in the parent application. When I invoke the service via browser(I've enabled HttpGet), I get a login prompt because the parent site requires a login. How do I disable this login prompt? I've enabled anonymous authentication for the webservice folder in IIS but I still get the prompt.

Comment: Sounds like you could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713192/disable-authentication-on-subfolders-of-an-asp-net-app-using-windows-authentic

Comment: I've tried it but I still get `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable basic authentication for the site you are referencing

[image]

Comment: My screen looks exactly like that except for the Forms Authentication. When I right-click on it, the Disable option is grayed out and in the properties window (right panel), it says "This feature has been locked and is read-only". The parent application is a Sharepoint project.

Comment: I would then make the service it's own site. IIS is expecting some sort of forms authentication for your site, there is a way around it, but you would have to create your own authentication process in your site. The easiest thing to do is to have the service in it's own site